# Is there away to use Google Dataflow to process Google Analytics Data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to use Google Dataflow to process Google Analytics data from many websites and store the results in a Google SQL.

But I was doing some research and I couldn't find a way to read the GA data from  Google Dataflow directly.

There is one way if you have Google Analytics 360 you can enable the bigQuery integration but I will be using the Free version of Google Analytics not the 360.

Has anybody worked with something similar?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

It would really depend on what type of data you're looking to pull. The GA360 integration with BigQuery extracts all the raw data (hit level) from Google Analytics. There is no way to do the *same thing* with the free version of Google Analytics.

However, you should be able to write your own Apache Beam Source that pulls data from Google Analytics using the [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). Of course you would be restricted by the API [limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas).

As I mentioned in the beginning of my answer, this all depends on what type of data you're trying to get at. Aggregated/high-level data should be possible but granular/hit-level data won't.